# External Pagination - DisplayTag or JMessa

Tags: google-app-engine, pagination, displaytag

Can someone please share complete code for external pagination using display tag in JSP and/or servlets. Please no hibernate, spring or struts 1 or 2. (I don't care if you have MySQL or DB2 or Oracle on the backend).

If you don't have this, can you send me code for jmessa in JSP or Servlet.

I'm on GAE and I need simple working code that has external pagination so I could integrate with GAE.

This would help immensely and save me some time!

Comment: SOers don't typically react well to "send me the codes" questions. It's expected you're prepared to spend at least some effort writing code yourself - we're not your unpaid freelancers.

Answer (score 0):

http://googcloudlabs.appspot.com/codelabexercise10.html